# How to roll back EF migration on Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

HELP!  I have an MVC4 app hosted on Azure.  I'm using EF code-first.  Here's my scenario:

1. I set a flag in my production database to cause the website to display a "website is disabled" message in lieu of the usual website behavior.
2. I published an update to the website code to the Staging instance.  When I ran the staging instance, it applied some migrations to the database schema.  At this point, the production instance would not work if I were to re-enable it because the database schema is not compatible with the production code
3. When I tested the staging instance, I discovered that it doesn't work correctly.

Now I realize that **I don't know how to back out the EF migrations that I applied** so that I can re-enable the Production instance and get back to where I was before I ran the Staging instance.  I know how to use the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio to go to a specific migration in the local database, but I have no idea how to manually tell Azure to update-database to a specific migration.

Answer (score 15):

Navigate to your database's dashboard on the Azure portal and select "Show connection strings". Copy the ADO.NET string into the `-ConnectionString` switch of the `Update-Database` command. You should end up with something like this:

```
Update-Database 
-TargetMigration {YourMigration} 
-ConnectionString "Server=tcp:{your server name}.database.windows.net,1433;
                   Database={your db};
                   User ID={your user}@{your server};
                   Password={your password};
                   Trusted_Connection=False;
                   Encrypt=True;
                   Connection Timeout=30;" 
-ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Also, make sure when you're in the package manager that your mobile service project is selected as the Startup Project. Add "-Verbose" to your command to help troubleshoot any other problems.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. When running in VS Package Manager Console I receive the error `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'`

Answer (score 3):

Run a `"Get-Migrations"`

it will display a list of migrations.

After that:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"{NAME_OF_SELECTED_MIGRATION}"
```

where {NAME_OF_SELECTED_MIGRATION} will be replaced with the name you want. 
PS: remove "{" and "}" characters.

Comment: Sorry, the question is really badly worded.  "Update-Database" works with my development environment, on my development PC.  The thing I don't know how to do is to roll back the production database on the Azure server to an earlier migration.  The migration info is in the database; I just don't know how to tell the Azure box to modify the database schema.

Comment: Update-Database is a command that you run on Visual Studio. So you just need to set your connection string to your production database on azure and do that.

Comment: Ok, up 'till now, I've treated the connection between the "migration" commands that I can issue in the Package Manager Console and the database as magic.  How do I wire up VS to talk to a database other than my development database?  Does that involve fiddling with the connection string in Web.config?  Can someone post an "answer" (rather than a comment) describing that procedure in reasonable detail?  That would appear to be the answer to my (poorly worded) question.  Thanks!

Comment: This saved my ass. Thanks. Just change your connection string to the affected db and run update-database to your last migration.